# Javascript call function inside html

Tags: javascript

My database is giving me week days as "0", "1", "3", "4", "5", "6". And I wanted to translate it to their actual name.

So I'm doing:

HMTL

```
<div><script>traduzir("<?php echo $row_room['weekday']?>")</script></div>
```

JS

```
<script>
    function traduzir (woord){
        if (woord == "0")
        {
            return "Domingo";
        }

        if (word == "1")
        {
            return "Segunda";
        }

        if (word == "2")
        {
            return "Terça";
        }

        if (word == "3")
        {
            return "Quarta";
        }

        if (word == "4")
        {
            return "Quinta";
        }

        if (word == "5")
        {
            return "Sexta";
        }

        if (word == "6")
        {
            return "Sabado";
        }
    };

</script>
```

I'm getting "traduzir is not defined" error. Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that the function `traduzir` is defined in the html before it is called.

Comment: This really calls for a switch statement. See here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Approaching your problem from a different point of view, can you do the translation server side in PHP before it's even rendered in the page?

Comment: Also, you have a typo where you use the vars woord and word

Answer (score 2):

First you need to make sure the script that defines the `traduzir` method is placed before the script that calls it.

Then you need to also change your script so that it actually does something with the returned value.

Comment: How do I use the returned value?

Comment: @Ana do you want to print it at the position you call the script ?

Answer (score 0):

If the section marked JS is in a separate JavaScript file, then remove the HTML (`<script>` and `</script>`).

In either case, move the second script so the HTML document loads it before the first script. You can't use a function until you have defined it, and it won't be hoisted from a later script in time to use it immediately in an earlier one.